# Is there a term that describes the set of professional skills of a person?

Tags: terminology

This set of professional skills can be used to determine which work is best for someone.

Example of use: The test yields that Marie has a good <term> for the project manager vacancy

Comment: Even when there is no exam or diploma learnt skills are commonly '*qualifications.*'  That doesn't fit your sentence because qualifications is plural.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**skill set**  [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/180865?redirectedFrom=skillset#eid1178255000) noun

> a range of skills or capabilities, esp. a set of skills necessary or
>   desirable for a person's participation in a particular field.

As in:

> The test yields that Marie has a good **skill set** for the project manager
>   vacancy.

Comment: +1 However, "**right** skill set" may fit better than "good skill set" in the context.

Answer (score 0):

**Expertise**:

expert skill or knowledge; expertness; know-how:

dictionary.com

Thus, your sentence would look like this:

> The test has shown that Marie has the necessary ***expertise*** for the
>   project manager vacancy.